# Dynamic language inside a javascript file

Tags: jquery, arrays, push

I'm creating a language file and need to push an array into the .js file from my .PHP file. In the JS-file I want to create an array of all words and use.

Any suggestions what I could do?

The language file structure:

PHP:

```
  $language = array(
    "se" => array(
     "jquery" => array(
                 "this_is_only_a_preview" => 'Detta är endast en förhandsvisning.',
                 "this_is_something_else" => 'Något annat.'

        )
      )
    )

       if ($_GET['lang']) {

       echo json_encode($language['se']['jquery']);

       }
```

And the JS:

```
   var language = [];

   $.get("../core.php?lang=1",
   function(data) {

            var json = JSON.parse(data);         
                $.each(json, function(key, value) {
                language.push({       
                    test: value
                });
            });

    });

    alert(language['value'])
```

Comment: `$.get()` is asynchronous. Your call to `alert()` will run before the JSON data has been received. The `language` array will not contain meaningful content until the callback you pass to `$.get()` has run.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call)

Comment: Will it not be possible to push values to an array inside the $.get call?